# Access singleton eventAggregator in WPF / Ninject

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ninject, caliburn

We are using WPF/Caliburn Micro and Ninject and have a bootstrapper that calls this :-

```
Bind<IEventAggregator>().To<EventAggregator>().InSingletonScope();
```

My underatanding is that this will be injected into the constructor parameter list each time an object is instantiated but there are occassions where the constructor has to be parameterless.  When we can have no parameters in the constructor how do we access the EventAggregator?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Service Locator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern).

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment:
`InSingeltonScope()` means that Ninject will create only one instance and **whenever it is asked** for an `IEventAggregator` it will return that one instance.  You still need a mechanism to *ask* for it; in the case of injection the constructor is asking for it to be injected.  If your constructor is parameter-less then the service locator is your way of *asking* for an instance.

**UPDATE 2**

Here are a few links that you might find useful:

http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/09/25/service-locator-pattern-in-csharpa-simple-example/

http://blog.longle.net/2012/02/15/wrapping-the-ninject-kernel-with-servicelocator/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.  Forgive my confusion but do we really need to use the service locator patten when the object is being declared as a singleton?  

The, perhaps incorrect, assumption was that the same singleton object would be used each time it is instantiated as that was the point of setting the singleton scope.

Comment: When you have declared the `IEventAggregator` as a singleton, it will only be instantiated **once**. But the singleton is contained within the Ninject kernel. You would therefore need a way to ask the kernel for the `IEventAggregator`, this is where the ServiceLocator pattern comes in. You use it to **ask** for the `IEventAggregator` outside a constructor (or inside a parameterless constructor). Alternatively you can use [Property Injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns)

Comment: Property Injection is also a good idea, but that assumes that you want whatever you're injecting to be a public property of the class you're constructing.  To me it seems like bad practice to expose a public property for something which the owning class is not responsible for, simply to allow it to be injected.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am very new to WPF so would you have an example of how to implement the service locator in this context?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you so much guys - i will digest all info tonight